# RabbitMQ cluster-operator does not work in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ cluster operator does not work in Kubernetes.
I have a kubernetes cluster 1.17.17 of 3 nodes. I deployed it with a rancher.
According to this instruction I installed RabbitMQ cluster-operator:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/quickstart-operator.html
`kubectl apply -f "https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/releases/latest/download/cluster-operator.yml"`
Its ok! but..
I have created this very simple configuration for the instance according to the documentation:

```
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: test-rabbitmq
```

I have error:error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "rabbitmq-server-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

after that i checked:
`kubectl get storageclasses`
and saw that there were no resources! I added the following storegeclasses:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

create pv and pvc:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-data-sigma
  labels:
    type: local
  namespace: test-rabbitmq
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: rabbitmq-data-sigma
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/rabbitmq-data-sigma"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-data
  namespace: test-rabbitmq
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

I end up getting an error in the volume - which is being generated automated:
[image]

```
FailedBinding   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

please help to understand this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) e.g. **Dynamic NFS provisioning** as describe in this [article](https://medium.com/@myte/kubernetes-nfs-and-dynamic-nfs-provisioning-97e2afb8b4a9) or you can manually create `PersistentVolume` ( it is **NOT** recommended approach).

I really recommend you to configure dynamic provisioning -
this will allow you to generate `PersistentVolumes` automatically.

#### Manually creating PersistentVolume

As I mentioned it isn't recommended approach but it may be useful when we want to check something quickly without configuring additional components.

First you need to create `PersistentVolume`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/rabbitmq # data will be stored in the "/mnt/rabbitmq" directory on the worker node
    type: Directory
```

And then create the `/mnt/rabbitmq` directory on the node where the `rabbitmq-server-0` `Pod` will be running. In your case you have 3 worker node so it may difficult to determine where the `Pod` will be running.

As a result you can see that the `PersistentVolumeClaim` was bound to the newly created `PersistentVolume` and the `rabbitmq-server-0` `Pod` was created successfully:

```
# kubectl get pv,pvc -A
NAME                   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                         STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pv    10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Bound    test-rabbitmq/persistence-rabbitmq-server-0                           11m


NAMESPACE       NAME                                                  STATUS   VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
test-rabbitmq   persistentvolumeclaim/persistence-rabbitmq-server-0   Bound    pv       10Gi       RWO                           11m

# kubectl get pod -n test-rabbitmq
NAME                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-server-0   1/1     Running   0          11m
```